# ARCORE with Android Studio(ArSceneView library)

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am using library ARSceneView  but by using this I am not able to rotate an object like when I use ARFragments, it has a function transformable node with extended function that helps to rotate an object but not in case of ARSceneView or can say that doesn't find anything (Code) that help me to understand how I will rotate a 3D model when user touches it after camera detect an image.Actually I find Pose function but I do not understand how it's work.
If anyone knows, kindly help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So if I understand it well, do you want to render a 3d model without the AR functionality (without camere image) like [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/1080/1*dxfc0B7XmWucGywciSM5IQ.png) ?

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/augmented-images-with-arcore-and-sceneform-4c3fe774b5bd I am following this one where 3D is place when image is detected.